# How to save the gpt-2-simple model after training?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, gpt-2, text-generation

I trained the [gpt-2-simple](https://github.com/minimaxir/gpt-2-simple) chat bot model but I am unable to save it. It's important for me to download the trained model from colab because otherwise I have to download the 355M model each time (see below code).

I tried various methods to save the trained model (like `gpt2.saveload.save_gpt2()`), but none worked and I don't have any more ideas.

My training code:

```py
%tensorflow_version 2.x
!pip install gpt-2-simple

import gpt_2_simple as gpt2
import json

gpt2.download_gpt2(model_name="355M")

raw_data = '/content/drive/My Drive/data.json'

with open(raw_data, 'r') as f:
    df =json.load(f)

data = []

for x in df:
    for y in range(len(x['dialog'])-1):
        a = '[BOT] : ' + x['dialog'][y+1]['text']
        q = '[YOU] : ' + x['dialog'][y]['text']
        data.append(q)
        data.append(a)

with open('chatbot.txt', 'w') as f:
     for line in data:
        try:
            f.write(line)
            f.write('\n')
        except:
            pass

file_name = "/content/chatbot.txt"

sess = gpt2.start_tf_sess()

gpt2.finetune(sess,
              dataset=file_name,
              model_name='355M',
              steps=500,
              restore_from='fresh',
              run_name='run1',
              print_every=10,
              sample_every=100,
              save_every=100
              )

while True:
  ques = input("Question : ")
  inp = '[YOU] : '+ques+'\n'+'[BOT] :'
  x = gpt2.generate(sess,
                length=20,
                temperature = 0.6,
                include_prefix=False,
                prefix=inp,
                nsamples=1,
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

The [gpt-2-simple](https://github.com/minimaxir/gpt-2-simple) repository README.md links an example [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VLG8e7YSEwypxU-noRNhsv5dW4NfTGce) which states the following:

> Other optional-but-helpful parameters for gpt2.finetune:
>
> - `restore_from`: Set to `fresh` to start training from the base GPT-2, or set to latest to `restart` training from an existing checkpoint.
> - ...
> - `run_name`: subfolder within checkpoint to save the model. This is useful if you want to work with multiple models (will also need to specify `run_name` when loading the model)
> - `overwrite`: Set to `True` if you want to continue finetuning an existing model (w/ `restore_from='latest'`) without creating duplicate copies.

The README.md also states that model checkpoints are stored in `/checkpoint/run1` by default and that one can pass a `run_name` parameter to `finetune` and `load_gpt2` if you want to store/load multiple models in a checkpoint folder.

Putting this altogether you should be able to do the following to work from saved models instead of re-downloading each time:

```py
import gpt_2_simple as gpt2

sess = gpt2.start_tf_sess()

# To load existing model in default checkpoint dir from "run1"
gpt2.load_gpt2(sess)

# Or, to finetune existing model in default checkpoint dir from "run1"
gpt2.finetune(sess,
              dataset=file_name,
              model_name='355M',
              steps=500,
              restore_from='latest',
              run_name='run1',
              overwrite=True,
              print_every=10,
              sample_every=100,
              save_every=500
)
```

See the source code for the [load_gpt2()](https://github.com/minimaxir/gpt-2-simple/blob/master/gpt_2_simple/gpt_2.py#L368) and [finetune()](https://github.com/minimaxir/gpt-2-simple/blob/master/gpt_2_simple/gpt_2.py#L126) functions for more specifics.